# How to capture only query strings using .htaccess PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess

> .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /cms_project
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} single(.*)
 RewriteRule  ^(.+)$ single.php?url=$1
</IfModule>
```

> URL: localhost/cms_project

```
//want to query strings single/posts/1/post-title
echo $_GET['url'];

OR

//function to get url query string convert it to an array
function getUrl() {
    if(isset($_GET['url'])) {
        $url = rtrim($_GET['url'],'/');
        $url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
        $url = explode('/', $url);
        return $url;
    }
  }
  print_r($_GET['url']);
```

> Now I want get url query strings, when I enter url like
> **localhost/cms_project/single/posts/1/post-title**
>
> Now I expect to get **single/posts/1/post-title** OR **['single','posts','1','post-title']** array
>
> But above code only return **['single.php']** array

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /cms_project

 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /single\.php\?url=(.*) [NC]
 RewriteRule ^single\.php$ single/%1 [L]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ single.php?url=$1/$2 [NC,L]  #OR ^single/(.*)$ single.php?url=single/$1
</IfModule>
```